# Loop through form values from a dynamic php form

Tags: php, html, forms, foreach

I building on top of an existing PHP based application to ability to update menu items name and prices.

I have generated a dynamic form which is populated with the results form the database. The idea is that the user can update the item name or price to update the information in the database.

The form works fine, but I am having dome trouble getting the info out of the form. each Item has a separate ID so I need to essentially do a foreach through the form and call the update function each time with the respective item id.

I can handle the DB side of things fine, but the application I am building on has a 'getInput' function to check input exists and to get the input form the form and I would like to use this.

This is the getInput function:

```
public static function exists($type = 'post') {
        switch($type) {
            case 'post':
                return (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;
            break;
            case 'get';
                return (!empty($_GET)) ? true : false;
            break;
            default:
                return false;
            break;
        }
    }

    public static function get($item) {
        if(isset($_POST[$item])) {
            return $_POST[$item];
        } else if(isset($_GET[$item])) {
            return $_GET[$item];
        }
        return '';
    }

}
```

The problem I have is when calling this function it only returns the last item form the form. Is there a way i can iterate though the form and get each item?

This is the dynamic form and the getInput code so far:

```
$menuItems = DB::getInstance()->get('menu_items', array('cat_id', '=', $cat_id ));

                    if($menuItems->count()) {

                        echo '<form class="updateMenu" action="" method="post">';
                        echo '<table  class="gridtable gridtableMenu">';
                        echo '<tr><th>Item Name</th><th>Item Price</th></tr>';

                            foreach($menuItems->results() as $item) {

                                echo '<tr>';
                                echo '<td class="menu-name"><input type="text" name="itemName" value="' . $item->item_name . '" required></td>';
                                echo '<td class="menu-price"><input type="number" step="any" name="itemPrice" value="' . $item->item_price . '" required></td>';
                                echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $item->id . '">';
                                echo '</tr>';

                            }

                        echo '</table>';
                        echo '<input type="submit" name="updateMneu" value="Update Menu">';
                        echo '</form>';

                    } else {
                        echo '<div class="error">No items have been added to this menu</div>';
                    }

            } // close categories foreach

        } // close if category set


        if(isset($_POST['updateMneu'])) {

            echo Input::get('id'), '</br>';
            echo Input::get('itemName'), '</br>';
            echo Input::get('itemPrice'), '</br>';

        } //close if isset updateMenu If
```

So I would like a foreach I think around this section:

```
if(isset($_POST['updateMneu'])) {

        echo Input::get('id'), '</br>';
        echo Input::get('itemName'), '</br>';
        echo Input::get('itemPrice'), '</br>';

        //update ite in the database, and move to gthe next item.

    } //close if isset updateMenu If
```

I will handle data validation and what not later on.

Comment: because of the name of your input type text i presume 
multiple `name="itemName"` , `name="itemPrice"` and `name="id" `

Comment: Hi, yes sorry i should have mentioned that. so id, itemName and itemPrice are obviously single items, there will be multiple of these in the form. and my current function to get the input just pulls the last one out of the form.

Comment: it can be done if the name is an array `name="itemName[]"`

Comment: Ahhh so simple, Thank you so much, it works perfectly. Now I can just loop through this based on the size of the Name array I should be good to go.

Thanks Again!

Answer (score 0):

As posted by 'noobHere' the answer was to set the input types name as arrays. e.g. `name="itemName[]"` instead of `name="itemName"`